# Laravel : How to set up consumable purchases?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to create consumable products in Laravel ?

Users can purchase different types of consumables, such as lives or gems in a game, to further their progress through an app. Consumable purchases are used once, are depleted, and can be purchased again.

Experts , any suggestions ?

Comment: It's a basic process of storing any purchased item in the database and removing it when used. Nothing too complicated really.

Comment: i want to implement pay as you go model in Laravel ? , any pointers ?